# Multi-homing: do i need Route metrics for 2 interfaces of which only one can access the internet?

Tags: routing, metrics, multi-homed

I have 2 multi-homed servers which, besides each being connected to the Internet via one of their NICs, they are also connected back-to-back to each other via their 2nd NIC.

I use `systemd-networkd` to configure DHCP for the Internet links and Link-Local IPs for their cross-connection. The cross-connection config file looks like:

```
$ less /etc/systemd/network/25-other.network
[Match]
Name=eth5

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
```

This works, and servers are assigned IPs like 169.254.245.165/16 on their secondary interfaces, respectively.

Not being very familiar with routing, I'm wondering if I can ever run into Internet connection issues due to routing. Does the kernel ever try to access the internet via the secondary interface? How is the decision made? I know route metrics can be used for this but unsure if I need them for my case (since no destinations are available via both interfaces), so do I need this?

```
[Network]
Metric=20
```

Or maybe this?

```
[Network]
RouteMetric=20
```

**Edit**: as the accepted answer says everything was fine without adding Routes. Posting the output of `ip route` if it helps anyone. It shows the default route going through my router and the 2nd route via the link-local IP.

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp111s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.11 metric 1024 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enpa1a2 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.2.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS uses the routing table `netstat -rn` to determine which interface to use.  You probably have a default route that uses the "internet" interface.  Unless you're doing something unusual, you don't need to mess with metrics.